# CORS Headers don't get set when calling spring security /login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need some help with my spring security 4.2 CORS configuration.

When calling the spring security login page http://localhost:8080/login, the CORS Headers are not getting set on the preflight requests.

When calling a different URL, the CORS headers are getting set correctly.

---

**Browser Console Error Message:**

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Chrome:**
[image]

**Spring Security 4.2**

```
    <!-- Main security configuration -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="mainEntryPoint">
        <security:cors configuration-source-ref="corsSource"/>

        <!-- Handle CORS (preflight OPTIONS requests must be anonymous) -->
        <security:intercept-url method="OPTIONS" pattern="/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll"/>

        <security:custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="mainLogoutFilter"/>

        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

   (...)

    <bean id="corsSource" class="org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource">
        <property name="corsConfigurations">
            <map>
                <entry key="/**">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration">
                        <property name="allowCredentials" value="true"/>
                        <property name="allowedHeaders" value="*"/>
                        <property name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
                        <property name="allowedOrigins" value="http://localhost:4200"/>
                        <property name="maxAge" value="86400"/>
                    </bean>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found in a different file that the login path configuration got overwritten. So the problem was specific to my project.

```
<security:http pattern="/login">
</security:http>
```

I leave to post up an an example for a working configuration.